# Why use"it" here?

Tags: adverbs

> He lives in a house with big trees all around it.

I know "all around" is a adverb, but what is the point of using the pronoun "it" behind a adverb used as an adverbial?

Comment: I'd say that 'all around' has a more extensive feel to me than 'all around it'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All around* can be an adverb; or rather, an adverb (*around*) modified by another adverb (*all*).

In this case, though, *around* is not an adverb, but a preposition, and *it* is its object.

There is a difference between saying *all around* (meaning ‘everywhere’) and *all around [object]* (meaning ‘surrounding [object] on all sides’).

You could move things around in the sentence and instead say:

> There are big trees all around the house he lives in.

I hope you can clearly see why just removing the object here would change the meaning rather radically: you'd end up with only “There are big trees all around”.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that there is no point at all. I would simply say 'I live in a house with big tress all around'. And I think I would be right in saying that that is how most competent native speakers would say it. The 'it' can be, and is usually and correctly, implied.

Edit 3 Jul 2020
I am not clear if those who believe that the "it" should not be elided, do so on the basis that the meaning changes without it - or whether the "it" absolutely has to be there. Having read @Janus' comments I am willing to concede that my earlier answer that "there was no point at all (in including "it") is incorrect. However I do believe that without the "it", it is still a valid sentence, albeit with a differently nuanced meaning.

Comment: The phantom strikes again!

Comment: I have to admit I think in this case the phantom was justified. There is certainly a point (grammatically, if not necessarily semantically in this particular context) to including the object _it_. Not my downvote, but I at least partly agree with it.

Comment: I too disagree with WS2's categorical statement (though I did not downvote). In this instance there's little difference but _She sat by the fire with cats all around_ and _She sat by the fire with cats all around her_ conjure up rather different pictures for me.

Comment: She sat looking at the distant swimming pool with bodyguards all around. oops, her.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But that is not a parallel example. You final object pronoun is essential. In the OP's example no such clarification is required. It is unlikely that the big trees would surround her rather than the house.

Comment: @WS2 But that is completely incidental and only the case because logic dictates that trees surround houses, not people. Leaving out the pronoun creates grammatical ambiguity, which it is then up to the logical coherence of the context to dispel, which is not no point at all to me. In addition, even in the asker’s example, leaving out the object gives it a different meaning to me. _All around_ just means ‘everywhere’ to me, so “in a big house with trees all around” could mean that there are trees both inside and outside the house; “all around it” cannot.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Are you suggesting that language must never allow the eliding of any pronoun, even where the meaning is quite clear without it? Would you therefore correct 'The wind was so strong that my hat was blown into the road' by adding 'by it' at the end?

Comment: @WS2 No, of course not. Note that you're not just eliding an object there, but the entire prepositional phrase; that is different. I'm just saying that the fact that a pronoun _can_ be elided doesn't mean that not eliding it is pointless. “Do you want to come with?” and “Do you want to come with me?” are both grammatical and mean the same thing; but including _me_ is not pointless—it's just a variant.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not sure I follow. (Should I have added 'you'?)'Do you want to come with?'does not seem grammatical (to me). But 'Do you want to come?' certainly would be. Moreover I am still straining every sinew to grasp the difference between 'living in a house with big trees all around', and '...with big trees all around it'.

Comment: @WS2 It is grammatical to some, though not all, speakers. To me “… with trees all around” can mean two things: 1) a house surrounded by trees; 2) a house with trees everywhere (whether in or out). More plausible if we say _flowers_ instead of trees, but still possible with trees. Adding the object removes this possible ambiguity. Even if there were no such ambiguity, saying that there is no point at all in keeping the object makes it sound like it _shouldn’t_ be there, which I disagree with—it's neither better or worse with or without it.

Comment: @WS2 But I was addressing the (second) question, while you just tackled the first. 'I know "all around" is a adverb, but what is the point of using the pronoun "it" behind a adverb used as an adverbial?'